# pdfcrop silent mode

Tags: includegraphics

I love pdfcrop in figure production but every time get to see:
"PDFCROP 1.38, 2012/11/02 - Copyright (c) 2002-2012 by Heiko Oberdiek."

With all respect: the first dozen times in a day I appreciate this but after hundreds of times it gets irritating.  Is there a silent mode?

Comment: `pdfcrop zzz.pdf zzzzz.pdf | grep -v Heiko` ?

Comment: `pdfcrop zzz.pdf > NUL` (or the equivalent for linux)? (there is no silent mode for this line).

Comment: @UlrikeFischer that would be `> /dev/null` but that would of course lose all messages not just the start banner.

Comment: @David Carlisle: | grep -v Heiko does it!  Many thanks.  Can you make this an answer that I can green?  (I hope Heiko is not offended in being grepped away.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can redirect the output to `/dev/null` (or `NUL` on windows) or to just lose that line but keep any other less expected messages, perhaps

```
pdfcrop zzz.pdf zzzzz.pdf | grep -v Heiko
```

Comment: The problem with this is that you lose the exit status from `pdfcrop`.  You probably want `set -o pipefail` too.

Comment: @richard or in bash look at `${PIPESTATUS[0]}`